# Default highstock zoom without rangeSelector buttons

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is there a way to set the default zoom on highstocks without having the selector buttons.
I have limited space, and dont want to use the default date ranges. instead I prefer to use the slider under the graph
But when I disable the rangeSelector, it defaults to using the whole range, rather than in my case, the last 24 hours.
I can get it to work by having only one button on the selector, but then its taking up space which could be used for the graph.

Any ideas on what I can do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the xAxis min and max option to get what you want. Disable the range selector and add the option to xAxis.

Check the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4txudb31/1/

```
    xAxis: {
        ordinal: false,
         min: fromtimestamp,
         max: totimestamp
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        enabled: false
    },
```